# How to set selected option for select with same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an array of objects with education data with AJAX and PHP. There can be up to 4 different `<select></select>` tags to display. How can I set the correct option for each select and remove the duplicate?

I tried this, which causes the duplicate:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Levels</label>
    <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
        <select type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Degree..." id="userEducationDegree educationCount + '" name="userEducationDegree[]">
            <option value="' +data.degree_name + '">' + data.degree_name + '</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Then I tried removing the duplicate with JS, which only works with the first select tag:

```
    var usedDegrees = {};
    $("select[name='userEducationDegree[]'] > option").each(function () {
        console.log("removing");
        if(usedDegrees[this.text]) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            usedDegrees[this.text] = this.value;
        }
    });
```

Current output what I have with the above setup is:

```
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
```

What I would like is that the one of `<option value="A">A</option>` is removed or that `<option>` is selected.

Comment: How do you identify the duplicate? Where is the sample input? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: @RobG check the edit pleaase

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement

> I would like is that the one of A is
>   removed or that  is selected.

we can select the option as per degree name. for this you can try this code

html:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Levels</label>
    <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
        <select type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Degree..." id="userEducationDegree educationCount + '" name="userEducationDegree[]">
           <option value="Select">Select</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
        </select>
    </div>
        </div>
```

js code will go like that

//lets degree_name='B';

```
 var degree_name='B';
        $("select[name='userEducationDegree[]'] option").each(function () {

            if(degree_name===this.value) {
                this.selected=true;
            } 
        });
```

Hope it will work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need to **select** the corrected value like you did. The duplicate option comes from your selection which is not required.

Just use the below line it will automatically select the `value` with **match** string.

**Jquery**

```
    $("select[id^='userEducationDegree']").val('A'); 

// in your case it should be data.degree_name instead of 'A'
```

Here is the **Snippet**

```js
$(function(){
   $("select[id^='userEducationDegree']").val('A');
  $("#sel").html('`'+$("select[id^='userEducationDegree']").val()+'`');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Degree..." id="userEducationDegree educationCount + '" name="userEducationDegree[]">
            <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<p>See <strong id="sel"></strong> is selected</p>
```

Comment: But what if the value is B?

Comment: Replace the `A` in `val('A')` with `data.degree_name` then it will automatically detect what to select wheter 'B' or 'C' or whatever if that exist in the options.